# Regex find content inside div and exact string

Tags: php, regex, string

I am using curl to get a large string on text and basically 3 things could happen the string could contain

1. a div with a unique name inside it for example `"class=\"asl bwd asd\">{Valid user}\u003C\/div>"`
2. `"The email you entered does not exist"`
3. a div with a unique name inside it for example `"class=\"asl bwd
   asd\">{UNIQUE STRING}\u003C\/div>"`

could someone help me write 3 separate preg matches so I can then do something if one of the three strings are found. The string will never have more than one of the three strings.

Comment: Try formatting your question in a way that it is readable

Comment: You need some kind of boundary for the `"Valid user"` case. Either it is at the end (or beginning) of the file, or it is space-separated, or it is followed by an HTML tag, etc.

Comment: Updated the question the Valid user is wrapped inside a div so might be easier to search for the div

Comment: Why do you think you need regular expressions for that? Why don't you just try with a simple string search? It should perfectly do the job. http://php.net/strpos - It helps a lot when asking question that you show the code you've done so far an ask about a concrete problem with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not try to parse XML or HTML with Regular Expressions. Neither is fully expressible using RegEx.

Use the [XML parser functions](http://php.net/manual/en/refs.xml.php) of PHP instead.

Or something like [PHPQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/) (I just found that one, I like the idea)